# Multi-dimensional array to key/value dictionary; returned from function, no control structures

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, key-value

Fairly simple; I'm just curious if there's a *better* way to accomplish this.

Given an array as follows:
<sub>(*the result of `preg_match_all()` with `PREG_SET_ORDER`*)</sub>

```
$matches = array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(8) "key=foo;"
    ["key"]=>
    string(3) "key"
    [1]=>
    string(3) "key"
    ["value"]=>
    string(3) "foo"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "foo"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(5) {
    [0]=>
    string(12) "pattern=bar;"
    ["key"]=>
    string(7) "pattern"
    [1]=>
    string(7) "pattern"
    ["value"]=>
    string(3) "bar"
    [2]=>
    string(3) "bar"
  }
}
```

I'd like to extract into an array, the following:

```
array(2) {
  ["key"]=>
  string(3) "foo"
  ["pattern"]=>
  string(3) "bar"
}
```

Essentially producing an associative array of `$array[$i]['key'] => $array[$i]['value']` for each `$i`.
<sub>(*If that sounds confusing, sorry, it's late*)</sub>

Anyway, this is trivial; however, I'm trying to accomplish this using PHP core `array_*` functions, that **return** the resulting array (*sorry `array_walk`*).

No `foreach`, or other looping control structures.

Right now, I've got it down to this:

```
\array_combine(\array_map(function($match) {
        return (string) $match['key'];
    }, $matches), \array_map(function($match) {
        return (string) $match['value'];
    }, $matches))
```

Which works, however it's not exactly succinct; I don't like it having to `array_map` twice -- once for keys, once for values.

Is there a more *elegant* solution, to extracting nested values from a well-formed multi-dimensional array, into a one-dimensional key/value pair dictionary?

Comment: `$a=[]; array_walk(function($m) { $a[$m['key']] = $m['value']; }, $matches);`

Comment: @kirilloid So close; I forgot to mention that `array_walk` is out because it returns `bool` rather than the resulting array. This call is being passed as an argument to another function, and the resulting array should be passed in. Thanks though!

Comment: You may wrap this call into another function. And I'm afraid, there's no shorter solution with such limited set of functions *allowed*.

Comment: @kirilloid That's what I thought; however I've been surprised at the ingenuity here before. I'm being anal about my code aesthetics, and having been so in the past proved successful with help from SO :) I can wrap yours up, even in a self-invoking closure to avoid an extraneous function definition; but I'm interested to see if someone can hack something together. Thanks all the same, I may end up wrapping yours for use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With php v5.3+:

*because of:*

> 5.3.0  Changed initial to allow mixed, previously integer.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php

```
$matches = array(
  array(
                'key=foo;',
    'key' =>    'key',
                'key',
    'value' =>  'foo',
                'foo',
  ),
  array(
                'pattern=bar;',
    'key' =>    'pattern',
                'pattern',
    'value' =>  'bar',
                'bar',
  ),
);

$a = array_reduce($matches, function ($b, $v) {
  return $b + array($v['key'] => $v['value']);
}, array());

print_r($a);

/*
Array
(
    [key] => foo
    [pattern] => bar
)
*/
```

Comment: Thanks @Yoshi -- Simple and elegant; spot on :)